# Copying very large strings in memory

Tags: c, memory

I'm trying to implement a solution to copy a large string in memory in C.

Can you give me any advice about implementation or any reference?

I'm thinking to copy byte by byte since I don't know the length (probably I can't calculate it with `strlen()` since the string is very large).

Another concern is that I will have to reallocate memory on every step and I don't know how is the best way to do that. Is there any way that I can reallocate using only the reference to the last position of the memory already alocated and filled? Thus if the memory allocation fails, it will not affect the rest of the memory already filled.

What is the best value to return from this function? Should I return the number of bytes that were succesfully copied?

If there is a memory allocation fail, does `realloc()` set any global variable that I can check in the main function after I call the copying function? As I don't want to just return `NULL` from it if at some point `realloc()` fails, but I want to return a value more useful.

Comment: Define "very large". Thanks.

Comment: Let's say tens of mbs

Comment: I don't suppose switching to a better string representation (storing the length instead of null-terminated strings) is an option?

Comment: Nope, I can't control that. Null terminated string is the string represetation that the function will get.

Comment: @unxnut It would be a good replacement for the byte copying, but doesn't solve the immediate problem of not knowing the length.

Comment: @Kevin will strdup work on strings that big? (tens of mbs)?

Comment: @rullof instead how can I realloc the memory?

Comment: Sure, why not? You should at least benchmark it against whatever else you try.

Comment: [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) reallocates a new string of the same length, I don't think it might help you much if you still want to append content to it... besides of that the first stirng is still there and you have to free it...

Comment: @A4L the point is to copy the string, you have to allocate a new string, and I would be astounded if it reallocated every byte one at a time.

Comment: You could also use a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), filling in the first n bytes and then doubling the allocated size every time you hit the max.  Though honestly I think the overhead of a strlen call is going to be smaller than any other solution besides maybe allocating, say, 100MB and realloc'ing it down to the necessary size when you're done.

Comment: @Kevin, actually the question is not very clear, if only a copy of a null terminated string is needed then `strdup` is the best choice.

Comment: Only tens of megabytes? There's no particular problem, then. Problems start appearing when you reach 2 GiB of data; then you have to start making sure you're using a 64-bit machine and appropriate types, but until then, it's just ordinary code with slightly bigger numbers than you're used to. What are you really trying to do? Your use case really isn't clear; it sounds like an XY Problem. Note that `strlen()` can handle strings of any size that the system can handle. And if you're handling massive quantities of data, you must know the size (or find it quickly); otherwise you can't work safely.

Comment: A good question I think ought to be asked aside from the issue of "how large is 'large'?" is why are you copying the string? Why can't you use it without copying it? Is it possible to restructure things to use only the single string since it is so large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `realloc()` failing

> If there is a memory allocation fail, does `realloc()` set any global variable that I can check in the main function after I call the copying function? As I don't want to just return `NULL` from it if at some point `realloc()` fails, but I want to return a value more useful.

There's no problem with `realloc()` returning null if you use `realloc()` correctly.  If you use `realloc()` incorrectly, you get what you deserve.

#### Incorrect use of `realloc()`

```
char *space = malloc(large_number);

space = realloc(space, even_larger_number);
```

If the `realloc()` fails, this code has overwritten the only reference to the previously allocated space with NULL, so not only have you failed to allocate new space but you also cannot release the old space because you've lost the pointer to it.

(For the fastidious: the fact that the original `malloc()` might have failed is not critical; `space` will be NULL, but that's a valid first argument to `realloc()`.  The only difference is that there would be no previous allocation that was lost.)

#### Correct use of `realloc()`

```
char *space = malloc(large_number);

char *new_space = realloc(space, even_larger_number);

if (new_space != 0)
    space = new_space;
```

This saves and tests the result of `realloc()` before overwriting the value in `space`.

### Continually growing memory

> Another concern is that I will have to reallocate memory on every step and I don't know how is the best way to do that. Is there any way that I can reallocate using only the reference to the last position of the memory already allocated and filled? Thus if the memory allocation fails, it will not affect the rest of the memory already filled.

The standard technique for avoiding quadratic behaviour (which really does matter when you're dealing with megabytes of data) is to double the space allocated for your working string when you need to grow it.  You do that by keeping three values:

- Pointer to the data.
- Size of the data area that is allocated.
- Size of the data area that is in use.

When the incoming data won't fit in the space that is unused, you reallocate the space, doubling the amount that is allocated unless you need more than that for the new space.  If you think you're going to be adding more data later, then you might add double the new amount.  This amortizes the cost of the memory allocations, and saves copying the unchanging data as often.

```
struct String
{
    char *data;
    size_t length;
    size_t allocated;
};

int add_data_to_string(struct String *str, char const *data, size_t datalen)
{
    if (str->length + datalen >= str->allocated)
    {
        size_t newlen = 2 * (str->allocated + datalen + 1);
        char *newdata = realloc(str->data, newlen);
        if (newdata == 0)
            return -1;
        str->data = newdata;
        str->allocated = newlen;
    }
    memcpy(str->data + str->length, data, datalen + 1);
    str->length += datalen;
    return 0;
}
```

When you've finished adding to the string, you can release the unused space if you wish:

```
void release_unused(struct String *str)
{
     char *data = realloc(str->data, str->length + 1);
     str->data = data;
     str->allocated = str->length + 1;
}
```

It is very unlikely that shrinking a memory block will move it, but the standard says:

> The `realloc` function deallocates the old object pointed to by `ptr` and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by `size`. The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of
>   the new and old sizes.
>
> The `realloc` function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same
>   value as a pointer to the old object), or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.

Note that 'may have the same value as a pointer to the old object' also means 'may have a different value from a pointer to the old object'.

The code assumes that it is dealing with null terminated strings; the `memcpy()` code copies the length plus one byte to collect the terminal null, for example, and the `release_unused()` code keeps a byte for the terminal null.  The `length` element is the value that would be returned by `strlen()`, but it is crucial that you don't keep doing `strlen()` on megabytes of data.  If you are dealing with binary data, you handle things subtly differently.

Answer (score 3):

`strlen()` won't fail, as it uses `size_t` to descirbe the string's size, and `size_t` is large enough to hold the size of any object on the machine the program runs on.

So simply do

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500 /* for strdup */
#include <string.h>

int duplicate_string(const char * src, char ** pdst)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == ((*pdst) = strdup(src)))
  {
    result = -1;
  }

  return result;
}
```

If this fails try using an more clever structure to hold the data, for example by chopping it into slices:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700 /* for strndup */
#include <string.h>

int slice_string(const char * src, char *** ppdst, size_t s)
{
  int result = 0;

  size_t s_internal = s + 1; /* Add one for the 0-terminator. */
  size_t len = strlen(src) + 1;
  size_t n =len/s_internal + (len%s_internal ?1 :0);

  *ppdst = calloc(n + 1, sizeof(**ppdst)); /* +1 to have a stopper element. */
  if (NULL == (*ppdst))
  {
    result = -1;
    goto lblExit;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    (*ppdst)[i] = strndup(src, s);
    if (NULL == (*ppdst)[i])
    {
      result = -1;

      while (--i > 0)
      {
        free((*ppdst)[i]);
      }

      free(*ppdst);

      *ppdst = NULL;

      goto lblExit;
    }

    src += s;
  }

lblExit:
  return result;
}
```

Use such functions by trying dump copy first and if this fails by slicing the string.

```
int main(void)
{
  char * s = NULL;

  read_big_string(&s);

  int result = 0;
  char * d = NULL;
  char ** pd = NULL;

  /* 1st try dump copy. */
  result = duplicate_string(s, &d);
  if (0 != result)
  {
    /*2ndly try to slice it. */
    {
      size_t len = strlen(s);

      do
      {
        len = len/2 + (len%2 ?1 :0);
        result = slice_string(s, &pd, len);
      } while ((0 != result) || (1 == len));
    } 
  }

  if (0 != result)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Duplicating the string failed.\n");         
  }

/* Use copies. */

  if (NULL != d)
  {
    /* USe result from simple duplication. */
  }

  if (NULL != pd)
  {
    /* Use result from sliced duplication. */
  }

  /* Free the copies. */
  if (NULL != pd)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; pd[i]; ++i)
    {
      free(pd[i]);
    }
  }

  free(pd);
  free(d);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: By definition, `size_t` can hold the length of the largest object the system can handle.

Comment: Err, didn't I wrote this? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: You wrote 'if the string is shorter'; there is no 'if' — a string cannot be longer than the maximum size that can be represented by `size_t`, and no sequence of bytes without a null terminator can be longer than the maximum size that can be represented by `size_t`.  So IMNSHO there is a difference between what I said and what you wrote.

Comment: I had "*shorter or equal*" first, but then the `0`-terminator came to my mind which from the user's perspective does not count for the string's length .. ;-)

Comment: On the second tought, you are correct with "*a string cannot be longer than the maximum size that can be represented by size_t*" but this only counts for the programs perspective. Couldn't we postulate a storage device which holds more data than a machine being able to access this storage device might be able to process? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: 1 TiB disk file on a 32-bit machine?  Or a 32-bit program…  Yes, but you still can't create a string bigger than the maximum size that can be stored in a `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's use Cunningham's Question to help figure out what to do. Cunningham's Question (or Query - your choice :-) is:

> What's the simplest thing that could possibly work?
>   -- Ward Cunningham

IMO the simplest thing that could possibly work would be to allocate a large buffer, suck the string into the buffer, reallocate the buffer down to the actual size of the string, and return a pointer to that buffer. It's the caller's responsibility to free the buffer they get when they're done with it. Something on the order of:

```
#define BIG_BUFFER_SIZE 100000000

char *read_big_string(FILE *f)  /* read a big string from a file */
  {
  char *buf = malloc(BIG_BUFFER_SIZE);

  fgets(buf, BIG_BUFFER_SIZE, f);

  realloc(buf, strlen(buf)+1);

  return buf;
  }
```

This is example code only. There are #includes which are not included, and there's a fair number of possible errors which are not handled in the above, the implementation of which are left as an exercise for the reader. Your mileage may vary. Dealer contribution may affect cost. Check with your dealer for price and options available in your area. Caveat codor.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

use a smart pointer and avoid copying in the first place